# Scaling only with AWS EC2 with Elastic Load Balancing and Auto-Scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scalability, amazon-elb

I am a start-up developer that just started learning network programming. I am at a stage to choose where to deploy my server.

I am using Netty for its performance and ease of use.

So here's my question. Is it possible to only use ELB  and Auto-Scaling when there is high-traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELB will pass through TCP and HTTP, you just need to set the ports you want.  Autoscaling will scale the servers based on a set of parameters.

So yes - you can - provided that your server can handle multiple instances of itself.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Peter, but you need to sit and configure the auto scaling, it doesnt happen automatically. FYI please refer to aws docs. Also you can read this [blog](http://geekospace.com/how-to-auto-scale-aws-ec2-instances-using-ec2-command-tools-api/)